# Exclude "Total" row in Google AdWords performance report

Tags: google-ads-api

I am downloading Ad Performance reports (in CSV format) using the .NET client library for Google AdWords API v201209.

The final row of data in every report I download is an aggregate row.  An example looks like:

```
Total, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --, --,2.6, --, --, --,516,13,16
```

I do not need the aggregate data.  Currently I'm stuck having to write code to remove it manually or deal with skipping this row during parsing.

Is there a way to exclude this row from being included in the downloaded report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible at the moment, I'm afraid. I usually request a numeric field at the beginning of each row, so I can filter out rows that I don't want; this also works for the header rows, which can't be removed either.

Comment: Thanks Ewan.  Can you elaborate on filtering out rows you don't want by requesting a numeric field at the beginning of the row?  I see your point but I don't see how it relates to filtering out the aggregate row.

Comment: As of now, this is possible by setting an [HTTP header](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/reporting#request_headers).

Answer (score 2):

For php users that uses googleads-php-lib:

```
$reportUtils = new ReportUtils();
$report = $reportUtils->DownloadReport($reportDefinition, null, $user, array('skipReportSummary'=>true));
```

Answer (score 1):

I use version 201509. You can suppress Totals as well as Report Header and Column Headers in report_downloader parameters

```
report_downloader.DownloadReport(
report, outputfile, 
skip_report_header=True,
skip_column_header=False,
skip_report_summary=True, 
include_zero_impressions=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now, you can set an [HTTP header](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/reporting#request_headers):

```
skipReportSummary: true|false | If true, report output 
                                will not include a summary 
                                row containing the report 
                                totals. If false or not  
                                specified, report output
                                will include the summary row.
```